# Selecting particular xml record with XSLT

Tags: xslt

Below is an example of my xml nodes. I want to take the active price record(status code=Active) with latest price date.
How can I achieve this?

```
  <price_record>
        <price>18.99</price>
        <price_date>20060724</price_date>
        <price_status_code>Active</price_status_code>  
        <seq_num>1</seq_num>
  </price_record>

  <price_record>
        <price>25.99</price>
        <price_date>20080725</price_date>    
        <price_status_code>InActive</price_status_code>   
        <seq_num>2</seq_num>
  </price_record>

  <price_record>
        <price>18.99</price>
        <price_date>20060928</price_date>    
        <price_status_code>Active</price_status_code>   
        <seq_num>3</seq_num>
  </price_record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your root element. The xslt below uses "catalog" as a root element, you can change that. The output is the sole record that matches your criteria.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <xsl:for-each select="price_record[price_status_code = 'Active']" >
        <xsl:sort select = "price_date" order="descending" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1" >
                <xsl:copy-of select = "." />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The sort should really be on just "price_date" not "price_record/price_date". Also you need to specify an order of "descending" otherwise it will be the earliest date, not the latest.

Comment: Edited above. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Why do you need the identity transform template in there?

Comment: I just added it in case there was more to his xml than just the price records. You think it's misleading?

Comment: I think it doesn't do anything, therefore it's redundant. ;-)